# Typing at grub command line and editor slow and error prone

Tags: grub2, keyboard

I recently needed to boot my Ubuntu 21.04 system in single user mode in order to correct a filesystem issue, which meant editing the `grub` boot instructions, and using `grub` was a remarkably painful experience.

Keypress response was remarkably slow, taking roughly a second for the keystroke to register. Even more maddening was the fact that frequently my input would repeat such that I would get two of the same characters, as if the keyboard's *autorepeat* was kicking in. Deleting the extraneous character was also annoying, since sometimes the `Del` key would "bounce" in the same way.

I tried a couple of different keyboards, since my preferred keyboard is admittedly a bit of a dinosaur, a *Sun Type 6 USB*.  I also tried the *Logitech* keyboard that was delivered with the system and it also produced the same spurious behavior.

Is there some `grub` or perhaps **BIOS** setting that needs to be changed or is this just "standard" behavior?

Please let me know if further information is required (such as the **BIOS** version) and I'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: I have the same issue on a fresh installed Ubuntu 20.04.3.